# Eliminar un object de un array mediante propiedad en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Quiero eliminar un object de un array(orderList) indicado en id del object, utilizando typescript.

Me estoy basando en la respuesta aceptada de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript). Pero no logro que se elimine el elemento del array.

```
// array donde se almacenan los elementos
public orderList: Array < Object > = [];

//metodo donde se alamacenan los elementos (funciona perfecto)
addProduct(product) {
    this.orderList.push({
        descripcionProducto: product.descripcionProducto,
        id: product.idProducto,
        total: product.precioProducto * product.cantidad,
    });
}
//salida de consola de orderList
// [{id:10,descripcionProducto:'Coca Cola', total: 100}, {id:11,descripcionProducto:'Fanta', total: 80}, {id:12,descripcionProducto:'Cerbeza', total:110}]


removeProduct() {
    let arr = this.orderList;
    let attr = 'id';
    let value = 11;
    let i = arr.length;
    // no se remueve el objecto con el id 11
    while (i--) {
        if (arr[i]
            && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr)
            && (arguments.length > 2 && arr[i][attr] === value)) {
            // remover elemento
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    // Devuvelve lo mismo
   // [{id:10,descripcionProducto:'Coca Cola', total: 100}, {id:11,descripcionProducto:'Fanta', total: 80}, {id:12,descripcionProducto:'Cerbeza', total:110}]
    return arr;
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

¿Por qué no se elimina el object mediante el id 12?

¿Este enfoque no es el adecuado para lo que necesito hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el método `removeProduct`, la condicion `arguments.length > 2` esta de mas ya que tu función no recibe parámetros.

### Solución:

```
removeProduct() {
    let arr = this.orderList;
    let attr = 'id';
    let value = 11;
    let i = arr.length;
    // no se remueve el objecto con el id 11
    while (i--) {
        if (arr[i]
            && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr)
            && arr[i][attr] === value) {
            // remover elemento
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, un error de novato.